WebSocket Connection Issue with Docker Compose and React JS
I'm encountering an issue with WebSocket connections when using Docker Compose to run a Kaldi server and a React JS frontend. The setup works fine when the Kaldi server is run in a container and the Node.js server is run on the local machine. However, when both are run in Docker containers, the WebSocket connection fails.
Docker Compose Configuration
Here is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'
services:
  websocket-server:
    image: alphacep/kaldi-ru:latest
    expose:
      - "2700"
    ports:
      - "2700:2700"

  frontend-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true

React JS Configuration
In my React JS frontend, I'm connecting to the Kaldi server using WebSocket. The WebSocket URL is configured as follows:
const URL = `ws://${process.env.REACT_APP_WS_HOST_NAME}:2700`;
I have set the environment variable REACT_APP_WS_HOST_NAME to "websocket-server" in the production environment used with Docker Compose.
Error Messages
When I run both services in Docker containers, I get the following errors:
Updated transcription:
LessonPage.js:40 WebSocket connection to 'ws://websocket-server:2700/' failed:
b @ LessonPage.js:40

LessonPage.js:76 WebSocket error: undefined No reason provided
d.current.d.current.readyState.WebSocket.OPEN.d.current.onerror @ LessonPage.js:76

LessonPage.js:69 WebSocket connection closed
LessonPage.js:71 WebSocket closed abnormally with code: 1006

LessonPage.js:103 [Deprecation] The ScriptProcessorNode is deprecated. Use AudioWorkletNode instead.
b @ LessonPage.js:103

LessonPage.js:141 Uncaught (in promise) InvalidStateError: Cannot close a closed AudioContext.

The WebSocket connection works fine when the Kaldi server is run in a container and the Node.js server is run on the local machine.
The issue only occurs when both services are run in Docker containers.

What could be causing the WebSocket connection to fail when both services are run in Docker containers?
How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
P.S.

i've tried to set the URL explicitly without envs:  const URL = 'ws://websocket-server:2700';
i've also tried to use network settings;
i've alsi ensured that kaldi image mapped to 0.0.0.0 adress
https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-server/blob/ddd8e93a95fc9dc09ea17f914e8834f62944e556/websocket/asr_server.py#L93


docker-compose exec frontend-server sh
# ls
README.md  build  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  
# wscat -c "ws://websocket-server:2700"
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)

